# How do you use block in other hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you use the block in other hand in Minecraft 1.10.2?

Answer (score 3):

You use it just like normal, by right clicking. But, it will only get used if you have nothing that can be used in your right hand, so you can right click and place blocks with the left hand if you have an item that cannot be used by right clicking in the right hand.

Answer (score 1):

The item in your left hand can't be used with left-clicking, only right-clicking. When you right-click, the game first tries to use the item in your right hand. If the item doesn't do anything when right-clicked, it "right-clicks" your left hand.

That means that when you have a a stone block in your left hand, and a dirt block in your right, you won't be able to place the stone, only the dirt. But if you have a non-right-clickable item in your right hand, you will be able to place your stone.